# Xamarin Forms: WebView data binding

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-webview

I'm trying to build a page which uses data binding to fill a `WebView` which is hosted on a `StackLayout`. Here's the XAML for that content page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="GES.Views.DetailsPage"
             xmlns:di="clr-namespace:GES.DI;assembly=GES"
             xmlns:c="clr-namespace:GES.Views.Converters;assembly=GES"     
             di:ServiceLocator.AutoWireViewModel="true"
             Padding="15, 10, 15, 10"
             Title="Ensino Superior">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <c:HtmlSourceConverter x:Key="htmlConverter"/>
            <Style x:Key="title" TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="Bold" />
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource colorPrimary}" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" />
            </Style>
            <Style x:Key="dateText" TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource lightGray}" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="Bold"></Setter>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <ScrollView>
                <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <Label Text="{Binding Path=News.Title}" 
                           Margin="0, 10, 0, 10"
                           Style="{StaticResource title}"></Label>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Path=News.PublicationDate, StringFormat='{0:dd/MM/yyyy}'}" 
                           HorizontalTextAlignment="End"
                           Margin="0, 0, 10, 10"
                           Style="{StaticResource dateText}"></Label>
                    <WebView Margin="0, 10, 0, 10"
                             Source="{Binding Path=News.Contents, Converter={StaticResource htmlConverter}}">
                    </WebView>
                </StackLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Since the `News.Contents` property returns an HTML snippet, I've built a custom converter to transform the text into an `HtmlWebViewSource`:

```
public class HtmlSourceConverter: IValueConverter{
    public object Convert(object value,
                          Type targetType,
                          object parameter,
                          CultureInfo culture) {
        var html = new HtmlWebViewSource();
        if (value is string h &&
            !string.IsNullOrEmpty(h)) {
            html.Html = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(h);
        }

        return html;
    }


    public object ConvertBack(object value,
                              Type targetType,
                              object parameter,
                              CultureInfo culture) =>
        throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Now, the problem. When the page is loaded, the `WebView` component will only render a small white rectangle...Rotating the device (ex.: going from portrai to landscape or vice-versa) does show the `WebView`'s content. For instance, lets assume I'm using the device in portrait mode. Loading the page shows the following:

[image: WebView loaded in portrait mode]

However, if I rotate my device, it will show the contents:

[image: WebView does show the text after rotating the device]

It looks like the WebView is not rendering correctly on first load...Btw, if I load the page on landscape, then I'll have to turn into portrait mode to see anything...

I've tried searching online and I did find an [old bug](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=21699), but it seems like it has been fixed (I'm using the latest stable version of the Xamarin Forms assembly)

Any clues on what's going on?

Comment: Have you tried setting the height of the webview explicitly?

Comment: not the requested height... i did try to use one of the fill options though...

Comment: There's an existing issue with webview in which the height is not updated dynamically and the height remains 0 as in the beginning. Let me know if it works.

Answer (score -1):

For anyone interested, I've followed this [post](http://lukealderton.com/blog/posts/2016/may/autocustom-height-on-xamarin-forms-webview-for-android-and-ios/) to create a custom webview renderer...